# CACHE, What is the best way for caching timeline events?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching, redis, memcached

The question is simple, I have a timeline of events or posts, like the facebook wall. I'm wondering what is the best way for to manage the caching here?
Things to take in account:

1. The collection of events is custom for each user, depending of their friends, and friends visibility, wich makes the database query a bit heavy.
2. Also the collection of events has pagination.
3. User must see new events, so not always showing the cached items, it remove the magic from the time line. *what should be the best invalidation time?*

If any one have some tips or advices I would be glad.

Comment: Check "redis in action" book. It has a complete section about a small social network, it is a great start.